Detection small object in game with yolov8 model
I've just started learning about artificial intelligence image capture.I learned that I needed a dataset, so I took a few screenshots.I labeled the objects with roboflow and trained the model with yolov8. But no matter what I did, I could not detect the fish (small, moving, shadowy) object correctly.I think the Preprocessing and Augmentation sections are very important in roboflow. I applied tiling, but I didn't understand what I should do on the code side. I'm so confused :D I need your help.
roboflow dataset:
https://universe.roboflow.com/test-uifst/test55/dataset/3
The model was trained on : https://colab.research.google.com/github/roboflow-ai/notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/train-yolov8-object-detection-on-custom-dataset.ipynb#
python :
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv
import mss
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

model = YOLO('best.pt')
sct = mss.mss()
monitor = sct.monitors[1]

while True:
    screenshot = sct.grab(monitor)
    img = np.array(screenshot)

    # RGB (3 CHANNEL)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)

    results = model(img)

    for result in results:
        for bbox in result.boxes:
            
            if bbox.cls == 0:  # "fish" 
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox.xyxy[0]



Please provide the command with which you have trained the model. Training parameters are important in this case

@hanna_liavoshka I added the link and did the model training there without making any changes.

Unfortunately it seems grabbing screenshot with mss is not working on my system, but I would suggest verifying if colors are indeed inverted. After this line img = np.array(screenshot) add two extra lines: cv.imshow("", img) and cv.waitKey(0) and confirm if displayed image shows inverted colors. Also try to grab smaller portion of the screen, change this line screenshot = sct.grab(monitor) to that screenshot = sct.grab((100, 100, 600, 600)) and place your fishes into box which left top corner is (100, 100) on the screen

@Greg0ry I will try it as soon as possible thanks for your comment.

@Greg0ry It worked for me, thank you. It doesn't detect it all the time, but it's better than not detecting it at all. In this way, I learned this code "sct.grab((100, 100, 600, 600))" and the size of the images is important when training and running the model.

I don't see your pictures but I would guess the objects you detect are very small :) You can use supervision slicing with inference, here is example https://github.com/roboflow/inference/pull/456/files#diff-ed7a6fa2a04994689784ed524e44c1b45786c2610d9dda5fcd936470bdd71dd3R191

As discussed in the comments, it seems the resolution of your screen is big enough to make it more difficult for model to detect small objects.
One solution is to take screenshot of smaller area and run inference on that instead of whole screen:
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv
import mss
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

model = YOLO('best.pt')
sct = mss.mss()
monitor = sct.monitors[1]

while True:
    screenshot = sct.grab((100, 100, 600, 600))
    img = np.array(screenshot)

    # RGB (3 CHANNEL)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)

    results = model(img)

    for result in results:
        for bbox in result.boxes:
            
            if bbox.cls == 0:  # "fish" 
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox.xyxy[0]

However it would be a challenge to ensure your objects are in the area.
You can also use Supervision InferenceSlicer
Nice blog post from supervision on detecting small objects: https://supervision.roboflow.com/develop/how_to/detect_small_objects/#inference-slicer
Below is your example modified to use slicer, I knocked it without checking if it runs so errors are expected, my intention was to give you an idea and a starting point:
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv
import mss
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time


model = YOLO('best.pt')

def slicer_callback(image_slice: np.ndarray):
    h, w, *_ = image_slice.shape
    result = model(image_slice)
    detections = sv.Detections.from_inference({
        "predictions": [
            {
                "class": bbox.class_name,  # your class name here, I guessed this property will be available
                "class_id": bbox.cls,
                "x": bbox.xyxy[0][0] + (bbox.xyxy[0][2] - bbox.xyxy[0][0]) // 2,  # center point
                "y": bbox.xyxy[0][1] + (bbox.xyxy[0][3] - bbox.xyxy[0][1]) // 2,  # center point
                "width": (bbox.xyxy[0][2] - bbox.xyxy[0][0]) // 2,
                "height": (bbox.xyxy[0][3] - bbox.xyxy[0][1]) // 2,
                "confidence": bbox.confidence,  # your confidence here, I guessed this property will be available
            },
            for bbox in result.boxes for result in results
        ],
        "image": {"width": w, "height": h}
    })
    return detections


slicer = sv.InferenceSlicer(
    callback=slicer_callback,
    slice_wh=(slice_width, slice_height),
    overlap_ratio_wh=(overlap_ratio_width, overlap_ratio_height),
    iou_threshold=iou_threshold,
    thread_workers=1
)


while True:
    screenshot = sct.grab(monitor)
    img = np.array(screenshot)

    # RGB (3 CHANNEL)  -- check if this step is required, cv.imshow("", img) before and after cvtColor
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)

    result: sv.Detections = slicer(image)

    fishes = result[result.class_id == 0]
    print(fishes.xyxy)

